# Only one fragment shown all time

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application I use three fragment activity for navigation drawer but on replacing one fragment with using fragment transaction always the last fragment is shown why?. Here is my code :-

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Log.d("position1", String.valueOf(position));
            fragmentClass = FarecardFragment.class;
        case 1:
            Log.d("position1", String.valueOf(position));
            fragmentClass = MybookingFragment.class;
        case 2:
            Log.d("position1", String.valueOf(position));
            fragmentClass = TrackingFragment.class;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you never break on your switch-case

```
  switch (position) {
      case 0:
         Log.d("position1", String.valueOf(position));
         fragmentClass = FarecardFragment.class;
         break;
      case 1:
         Log.d("position1", String.valueOf(position));
         fragmentClass = MybookingFragment.class;
         break;
      case 2:
         Log.d("position1", String.valueOf(position));
         fragmentClass = TrackingFragment.class;
         break;
}
```

The break statements are necessary because without them, all statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of their  case labels, until a break statement is encountered or the cases end.